# Swift: Why my Buttons will be duplicated every time I scroll down and up?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)

    if checkIfOutOfRange.getElement(at: indexPath.row) != nil {
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row] = UIButton(type: .custom)
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].addTarget(self, action: #selector(hearVoice), for: .touchUpInside)
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].setImage(UIImage(named: "play")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].layer.borderWidth = 2

        if self.sortedUserVoice.count > 0 {
            if self.sortedUserVoice[indexPath.row].userUid == self.finalUserUid {
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                cell.addSubview(cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row])
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            } else if self.sortedUserVoice[indexPath.row].userUid == self.userOppositeID {
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                cell.addSubview(cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row])
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                cellPlayerBtn[indexPath.row].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code checks if the buttons have already been added to the cell when it's reused. You could implement `prepareForReuse` to return your cell to a pristine state before being reused.

Comment: Or move this code out of `cellForItemAt` (it doesn’t really belong there anyway) and into a `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses’ appropriate `init` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you remove the addSubview method from cellForItemAt indexPath and implement it directly in a UICollectionViewCell subclass. Now, depending upon your finalUserUid or userOppositeID, you can hide or show the UIButton. This way, the collection view's cell gets reused, and it is an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: I implemented my Buttons directly in a UICollectionViewCell subclass and then it still works! Thank you all again!